# While downloading some content from a website after few times i got exception webexception 502 Bad gateway what could make that?

Tags: c#

This is the download code:

```
private string downloadContent()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return content;
        }
```

The exception was on the line:

```
response = request.GetResponse();
```

This is the Exception:

```
system.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at ChatrollLogger.Form1.downloadContent() in D:\C-Sharp\ChatrollLogger\ChatrollLogger\ChatrollLogger\Form1.cs:line 228
       at ChatrollLogger.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\ChatrollLogger\ChatrollLogger\ChatrollLogger\Form1.cs:line 112
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

What could be the problem ? Im downloading the ocntent from the site each n seconds.
Most of the times no problems so far i got this exception once only.

Line 112 is:

```
string content = downloadContent();
```

And line 228 is:

```
response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Sounds like you got an error.  Sometimes it happens... that internet is a wild place.

Comment: That's an error from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(502) Bad Gateway could mean that the remote server is having trouble (site down, server being restarted etc)

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

```
10.5.3 502 Bad Gateway

The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the 
upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Comment: Voltagex so using try and catch in the downloadContent()  will be a good idea ? I mean all over the code in the downloadContent function to put under try and catch ?

Comment: Yes, from GetResponse to return.